# Use a Google plus page as "author"

Tags: google-plus

I would like to add the "link" tag to my site with "author" attribute.

Generally it could be useful to insert a g+ profile link, but is it a good idea to put, instead a profile, a g+ page? Or in this way I've not benefits of add this tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell whether Google accepts a page instead of a profile,
but I can tell you that the Google Webmastertools offer a way to try it:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Insert your URL or HTML and give it a try.

I have the page in german, but you'll get a green "author successful" message if it works,
it will display your profile link and name.

Comment: Interesting, it seems ok. But if I search on google does not appear, perhaps because I've added the link yesterday (link as publisher, not author). Try on that tool "www.ildeposito.org" if you have some minutes

Comment: It's working. It takes a few days for Google to update (all) your site(s), be patient and take care that on all your pages the link is working the same.